# How to read objects from Json File in dart and Map to variables?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a JSON file with different and unique objects as Employee1, employee2 and so on. Now I want to read the JSON file using the unique objects and then map the object contents to a variable and use it in my project.

the JSON file is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "employee1": {
            "firstName": "Lokesh",
            "lastName": "Gupta",
            "website": "howtodoinjava.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "employee2": {
            "firstName": "Brian",
            "lastName": "Schultz",
            "website": "example.com"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

feed the above json list to `json.decode()`

```
var dJson = json.decode(list);
//which results in dJson being a List<dynamic>
//access the first result
var first = dJson[0];
//which gives you a Map because the json.decode maintains the structure of the json given
var employee1 = first["employee1"];
//will give you another Map
var firstName = employee1["firstName"];
//will give you the firstName
print(firstName);//Lokesh
```

Comment: then for accessing employee2 I would have to increment ```dJson[1]``` and then follow the same steps as you have done for employee1 right?

Comment: Worked as expected as you explained in the code. And Really sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Is there a way I can search for ```employee1``` in the same JSON file  then map that to a variable

Comment: Did the job,  modified the ```JSON``` Syntax to match the ```Map``` syntax and solved my part thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Just check out this example that I have created:
Following is the json that you provided.

```
[
    {
        "employee1": {
            "firstName": "Lokesh",
            "lastName": "Gupta",
            "website": "howtodoinjava.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "employee2": {
            "firstName": "Brian",
            "lastName": "Schultz",
            "website": "example.com"
        }
    }
]
```

This is the solution :

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}

class Employee {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String website;

  Employee({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.website});
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _isLoading = false;

  List<Employee> employeeList = List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
    String data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/parse.json");

    var jsonData = json.decode(data);

    jsonData.forEach((item) {
      item.forEach((key, value) {
        employeeList.add(Employee(
            firstName: value['firstName'],
            lastName: value['lastName'],
            website: value['website']));
      });
    });

    print(employeeList.length);

    employeeList.forEach((item) {
      print(item.firstName);
      print(item.lastName);
      print(item.website);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Text(''));
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to create a model out of the JSON you are getting. For the sample provide the Model, would look like this.

```
class EmployeeModel {
  Employee1 employee1;

  EmployeeModel({this.employee1});

  EmployeeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    employee1 = json['employee1'] != null
        ? new Employee1.fromJson(json['employee1'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.employee1 != null) {
      data['employee1'] = this.employee1.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Employee1 {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String website;

  Employee1({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.website});

  Employee1.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    firstName = json['firstName'];
    lastName = json['lastName'];
    website = json['website'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['firstName'] = this.firstName;
    data['lastName'] = this.lastName;
    data['website'] = this.website;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Then use

```
EmployeeModel employee = EmployeeModel.fromJson(responseJSON);
```

to access the values within the model.